# $data is not returning result

Tags: php, pdo

I need the $data to return from the database if the data was found from the database, but unfortunately, my code is not working to return the data.

I tried to enter non-exist data, it managed to return the error message but if the data exist, the page displays nothing.

May I know where did I go wrong in my if statement?

Below is my code that contain after the $data return the script will execute.

```
$day  = $_POST['day']; 
$month = $_POST['month']; 
$year  = $_POST['year']; 
$dob = implode('/', array($day,$month,$year)); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    if(empty($_POST['day']) || empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['year'])){ 
        echo "You need to fill in each field.<br /><br /><a href=\"./\" title=\"Fill In Again\">Click here to <b>fill in each field</b> again</a>"; 
    exit; 
    } 
} 

//Date that user keyin 
$userDate = $dob; 
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userDate); 
$myFormat = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d'); 

//Query string and put it in a variable. 
if(isset($_POST['dob_chi'])){ 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_n WHERE dob_chi = :date"; 
} else { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_n WHERE dob_eng = :date"; 
} 

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute(array('date' => $myFormat)); 
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
if ( !$data ) { 
    echo 'No data found in database!'; 
    exit; 
} else { 
    return $data=$userDate; 
} 

//Now we create a while loop for every entry in our DB where the date is match. 
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) { 
    $r1          = $row->rowone; 
    $r2          = $row->rowtwo; 
    $r3          = $row->rowthree; 
    $englishdate = $row->dob_eng; 
    $chinesedate = $row->dob_chi; 
    $zodiac      = $row->zodiac; 

    //add all initial data into a matrix variable for easier access to them later 
    //To access rowone use $rows[0][0], rowtwo $rows[1][0] ect. 
    //The matrix is an array which contains multiple array. eg. 2-dimensional arrays 
    //To get all the variables with $r1X simply retrieve the first array of the matrix eg $rows[0] 
    $rows = array(array($r1),array($r2),array($r3),array());        
} 
//Similarities between row1 and row2 made me incorporate modulo value as an argument. 
function incmod($a, $m){ 
    return ($a % $m) + 1; 
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean by `return`? An output?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your `return` statement ends the function, so you never execute the `while` loop.

Comment: Have you trined to use `echo` instead of `return` ?

Comment: You're also overwriting `$data` when you do `$data = $userDate`. You can't use `fetchObject` after calling `fetchAll`, because that fetches all the results.

Comment: I don't understand why you need that `while` loop. You already have all the rows in `$data`, why do you need to make a new array `$rows`?

Comment: "return $data=$userDate;" makes little sense. When you return, the method stop and returns the value/data inside the variable to the right, not the variable itself :)

Comment: @Barmar previously the bottom script start from `$rows = array(array($r1),array($r2),array($r3),array());` is use for manual form key in, now I amend it to work from database rather than manually key in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the line:

```
return $data=$userDate;
```

because it's ending your script and also overwriting the `$data` variable.

Change:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Then change the line:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
```

to:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
```

Comment: it show this error `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_OBJECT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\jeff\result.php on line 30` besides that I get rid the line `return $data=$userDate;` and now it left only `if ( !$data ) {
    echo 'No data found in database!';
    exit;
}`

Comment: Sorry, small mistake it should be `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Comment: thank you very much! it solve my whole nights problem!!

Comment: as you can clearly see from his code, he don't need no foreach at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I said that in my comments to the question. He seems to want to convert the objects into indexed arrays, I'm not going to argue with him over that, even though it's misguided.

Comment: I guess he has some other code that's expecting the data in that format, so this code needs to transform it.